# Повторное использование обработчиков в Callback Service

Tags: c++, grpc

Разбираюсь с `grpc::CallbackGenericService`

В gRPC есть понятие `Reactor` - обработчика вызова.

Хочу создать пул таких объектов(`map<method_name, pool_of_reactors>`).

Безопасно ли повторное использование объектов обработчиков или нужно на каждый вызов создавать новый?

Для вызова с клиента вроде бы нужен новый объект контекста.
Для серверной части я подобного не видел.

P.S.: задача - прикрутить кастомный сериализатор